# Same Token get generated for all thread - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, token

Case: First time default value will be used as accessToken and then extracted accessToken from response will be used. Using Regular Expression I have extracted the accessToken.

Problem: Same Token get generated for all thread.

Scenario:1 Number of Thread 10 and run; for all ten users default token get displayed.
Scenario:2 Number of Thread 20 and run. This time for 10 users unique token get generated; but for next 10 users default token get displayed.  I have attached the JMX File https://filebin.net/qmsw7jkmwtu229rl.

Please correct me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts**. According to [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, so the references **will only be resolved once**. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error

So change [`${__threadNum}` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) call in your Groovy scripts to `ctx.getThreadNum()` (where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)) and your approach should start working as expected.

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter